# Converting character date ("01OCT2014") to DATE format In R

Tags: r

I am new to **R**, and having trouble converting my characters to a`DATE` format.

I have looked at [Converting character into a Date format [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552688/converting-character-into-a-date-format)
 and tried using the suggestions there, but I keep getting `NA`'s instead.

```r
library(zoo)
t<-as.yearmon(select.oneseries$SERIES_DT)
str(select.oneseries$SERIES_DT)
str(t)
```

When I execute the code, I get the following results

```
chr [1:18] "01OCT2014" "01JAN2015" "01APR2015" "01JUL2015" "01OCT2015" ...
'yearmon' num [1:18] NA NA NA NA ...
```

my expectation is `t` to be populated with actual `DATE` formats instead of `NA`s.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use lubridate package.
Then you deffine order of day, month and year in string.

```
library(lubridate)

dmy('01OCT2014')
```

Comment: thanks! just a quick question, what is the next steps after defining it? Should it be as.Date(select.oneseries$SERIES_DT,format="dmy")?